# Can I add an atomic operation to MemoryCache?

Tags: .net, caching, .net-4.0, memorycache

I'd like to know if I can implement a method on MemoryCache that removes an item from it and add a new one before any other thread tries to reach it. I can't seem to find anything that would let me control the lock(maybe for a good reason) so I can perform these two operations at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "with the same key", then use the indexer:

```
cache[key] = value;
```

If you mean with different keys, then: no

Comment: No, with another key actually.

Comment: @Haciogullari then: no. In many cases it is possible to avoid an issue here by *ordering carefully*.

Comment: What do you mean by ordering carefully?

Comment: Actually CacheItemPolicy includes a CacheEntryRemovedCallback. It may accomplish what I need.  I'll take a look at it.